# Angular 4 - Using Object.assign with RXJS Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I'm new to Observables and still trying to get my head around exactly how they work.

I'm trying to take an array from an observable and allow it to be changed, but without affecting the observable. I thought I'd be able to do this with Object.assign()

The flow is:

1. Get an array of invoices from the API.
2. Store it as a BehaviorSubject Observable in a service.
3. User navigates to 'view all invoices' screen.
4. User clicks on 'Edit' one invoice
5. Edit component loads, subscribes to the Observable, finds the correct invoice from the array and assigns it to a separate `this.invoice` object.
6. User should be able to edit `this.invoice` without affecting the observable

But no. 6 doesn't work. If the user clicks on Edit invoice, makes a change to the invoice, doesn't save it to the DB but instead goes back to the view invoice screen and clicks edit again, the changes persist. I would expect the original invoice to be shown, not the newly edited one.

In user.service:

```
export class UserService {
  ...
  public invoices: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  ...
  constructor(){
  };
}
```

Get the invoice array:

```
userLogin() {
  this.commonService.request('login', '', {password: this.password, email: this.email})
    .then((response:any) => {
      ...
      if(response.invoiceData) this.userService.invoices.next(response.invoiceData);
      ...
      }
    })
}
```

View invoices component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.invoicesSubscription = this.userService.invoices.subscribe((invoices) => {
    if(invoices) {
      this.invoices = invoices;
    }

  });
}
```

Edit invoice component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
    if(params) {
      this.invoicesSubscription = this.userService.invoices.subscribe((invoices) => {
        if(invoices) {
          invoices.forEach((invoice) => {
            if(invoice._id == params.invoiceId) {
              this.invoice = Object.assign({}, invoice); 
              console.log(invoice) // This shows changes to the invoice when the screen loads for the second time.
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

How can I edit `this.invoice` object without the changes affecting the Observable?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(invoice))` instead of `Object.assign({},invoice)`. in the edit invoice component.

Comment: You ninja'd my answer ;P. Yes, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is a way to make a in-depth clone of an object. Simple, but be aware that it may be ineffective for large objects (or with objects with circular references). For invoice objects it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Observables only let you treat data as streams, where you can do awesome stuff with it by using operators. But they don't "store" data in any way - They only see a list of elements that get served to the observers, leaving the data transformation part to the consumer.

`Object.assign({}, obj)` doesn't do a depth-copy of an object. In your case making changes on the level of `this.invoice` shouldn't get back to the original object that's lying in the BehaviorSubject (for instance `this.invoice.foo = 'bar'`), but if you go just one level deep, it will (for instance `this.invoice.items.push('bar')`)

You will need to make a whole copy of your object (search around, there are many ways to do that). You can also use `Immutable.js` to help you in that, but it's a bit of a pain to work with them... (it's a library that lets you store immutable data: Data that if you want to change some part of it, it will give you a whole new copy of the object with the change you needed, leaving the original intact)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, it's starting to make sense: The changes I was making to `this.invoice` were pushes and pulls - are you saying that kind of change is different to `this.invoice.foo = 'bar'`? ('Different' as in the changes from a push will happen in the original object as well). As in my own answer, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(invoice) is working, but I'd like to understand properly why.

Comment: @RunnyYolk It's just on what level are you making changes. `this.invoice.push()` should work properly (but I don't think you did that), and in my example it's not only for push, if you do something like `this.invoice.address.zipCode = 'bar'` the change will also get reflected in the behaviour. [continues...]

Comment: What `Object.assign({}, invoice)` does is create a 1-level copy of `invoice`: So the object that it returns is a new object where it's property-values are those of the original invoice. If they are primitives (string/numbers), then they are copied as well, but if they are objects or arrays, it shares the reference on the original and in the copy. So a change in the invoice copy in that reference will also reflect on the original.